# C++/CLI or C# P/Invoke for a big C library, calling an extern function

Tags: c, dll, c++-cli, pinvoke

Now I know there are quite a few questions regarding this but in general they refer to c++ libraries.

I have a fairly important C dll (approximately 2800 functions) and I need to make an API for about 70 of these callable in C#. I started off using P/Invoke but it's pretty tedious because I have complex structures to pass and return from the C code (structures with pointers to others, double pointers, etc) and it's taking me alot of time to get what I need.

Now I don't know C++/CLI at all but I have a bit of experience with C++ (not a lot though).

I am wondering if it's worth making the effort to learn this for my project. Will using a C++ wrapper enable me not to have to struggle with marshalling structures, allocating pointers in global heap, etc or not?....

Thanks a lot and big ups to this great community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to deal with native structs from C#. So writing a C++/CLI wrapper is easier. You can convert/wrap those structs to `ref classes` without too much trouble and use them in C#.

```
void some_function(Some_Struct * ss)
{
  //...
}

struct Some_Struct
{
  int intVal;
  double dblVal;
}

//C++/ClI
public ref class Wrapper
{
  public:
    void CallSomeFunction(int intval, double doubleval)
    {
      Some_Struct * ss = new Some_Struct(); // maybe malloc is more appropriate.
      ss->intVal = intval;
      ss->dblVal = doubleval;
      some_function(ss);
      delete ss; // or Free(ss);
    }
}

//C#
Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
wrapper.CallSomeFunction(10,23.3);
```

Answer (score 6):

That's quite a large surface area. I think C++/CLI will be easier than P/invoke. You don't need to use any C++ features, you can write what is essentially C and compile and export it with C++/CLI.

Comment: Thanks.
Just to make sure I get you well, what I need to do is compile my current dll in C++/CLI? And once I have that all is ok for use in C#? Or do I need to write c++ classes? The articles I read regarding C++/CLi wrappers all mention creating a class for every existing C++ class... Since I don't have any classes I can't figure out how to go about it... If you have a tutorial or example it would be great!

Comment: No, I think you are better leaving your DLL as it is and writing a C++/CLI wrapper to that. The C++/CLI wrapper can call the native DLL and also export a managed interface to your C# code on top.

Comment: @Nchek: Typically you want to take the object files that are currently part of your native DLL, before linking, and link them statically with your new C++/CLI code, to create a single DLL (gets rid of installation headaches, can be installed in the Global Assembly Cache, etc).  But there's no reason to use `/clr` on your existing code.

Comment: Yes, what @Ben says is very good too. If your C DLL is consumed by other parts of your app then you may want to retain it. Otherwise linking objects directly into the C++/CLI code is ideal.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Ok thanks for the advice. But I have 32 projects and loads of object. I actually barely understand the structure of the solution. For now I've just compiled it copied the output dll for PInvoke... So I don't think I'll be able to do what you said...

Comment: Hi. I searched and was surprised that I couldn't find out how to call my C dll from C#? I can't add a reference to it in VS because it's unmanaged... So what can I do to import the functions? Dllimports?

Comment: You don't call the C DLL from C#. You call the C++/CLI DLL from C#. From C++/CLI you either link the objects directly, or link to the native C DLL in the traditional manner (with .h and .lib files).

Comment: Oups I meant to write from C++. Ok well my question is then how do I link the link to the native C dll (sorry for the basic question)

Comment: Include the .h file and link against the .lib file.

Comment: @Nchekwube: You link a .lib file, either a containing object code for the C functions, or an import library telling the compiler how to find those functions in a DLL at runtime.  The linker should generate an import library alongside the DLL when you build the C code.

Comment: When using the C header files, you most likely will need `extern "C" { #include "Ccode.h" }`, or else name mangling will cause problems.

Comment: wow ok... Thanks for all the help. To recap: I have a C dll. the `extern "C" {}` is already in it to export the functions. Now how do I do the linking in a visual studios c++/cli library project?

Comment: Update: I've update my question because I have solved part of the problem. Nevertheless I'm getting a "more than one storage class specified" error at compilation.

Comment: Please don't ask more and more questions in the same question. Ask a new question.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that. It's done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428789/calling-a-native-c-compiled-with-vs-2005-from-c-cli-visual-studio-2010